# Scramble String According to Array Values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Trying to solve [this question](https://www.codewars.com/kata/string-scramble/train/javascript) on Codewars.

I've seen [other articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array) that deal with shuffling / scrambling a string randomly.

But what about scrambling a string according to the values in a given array?

I.e. `abcd` given the array `[0, 3, 2, 1]` will become `acdb` because:

- `a` moves to index `0`
- `b` moves to index `3`
- `c` moves to index `2`
- `d` moves to index `1`

My guess is to start out by splitting the string into an array. And then we want to get the index value of the array that's passed into the `scramble` function, and push the character at the index value from that array into the new array. And finally join the array:

```js
function scramble(str, arr) {

  let newArray = str.split("");
  let finalArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    console.log(newArray);
    finalArray.push(newArray.splice(arr[i], 1));
  }
  return finalArray;
}

console.log(scramble("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]));
```

But the problem with this logic is that `.splice()` removes the character from the `newArray` every time.

Is there another method that will remove the character at the specified index without modifying the original array?

I don't think slice will work either.

Comment: Your question is not consistent; you ask how to remove something from an array with affecting the array. The answer is "you can't" -- that's the definition of "remove". If you just want to get a character at a specific index, that's what `slice` is for...

Comment: What happens if you provide an array that is not the same length as the string? Or would this never happen?

Comment: @zfrisch according to the coding challenge, this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the input string get the character at the current position using **string.charAt(position)** and put it into a new array into the position retrieved from the positions array.

```js
function scramble (str, arr) {
let newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newArray[arr[i]]=str.charAt(i);
  }
  return newArray.join();
}

console.log(scramble("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: You can also just use `str[i]`, there's no need to call a function.

Comment: I did not realize you could simply _assign_ the string values to the `newArray` like that. That is much simpler than trying to push into a new array. With a `return newArray.join()` at this end, this works.

Comment: @Barmar - cool! Good to know - though I'm not sure what is happening behind the scenes if I use array access on a string.

Comment: @HappyHands31 - Glad I could help! =)

Comment: Nothing special is happening. EcmaScript 5 simply added this as an equivalent feature. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access

Comment: Thanks, but why the second edit? Function must return a string.

Comment: Ah sorry @HappyHands31 I didn't realize you edited it. I was fixing a small typo - I forgot a semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a separate array to store the letters.

```js
var str = "abcd";
var arr = [0, 3, 2, 1];
function scramble(s, a) {
    var ar = Array(a.length);
    a.forEach((e, i) => {
        ar[e] = s[i];
    });
    return ar.join('');
}
console.log(scramble(str, arr));
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could make a "blank" array of a specified length. And like the other answer, _assigning_ the string index values to the newArray values is much more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

Use `reduce` on the array and as the array is iterated assign the character of the iterator index(`i`) in the string(`s`) to the value index(`v`) of the new array(`ra`). After the `reduce` completes, use  `join` to turn the returned array(`ra`) back into a string.

```
let scramble = (s, a) => a.reduce((ra,v,i)=> (ra[v] = s[i], ra), []).join("");
```

---

### Example:

```js
let scramble = (s, a) => a.reduce((ra,v,i)=> (ra[v] = s[i], ra), []).join("");

console.log( scramble("abcd", [0,3,2,1]) );
```

---

### Clarification Code:

I realize the above code may be hard to wrap your head around. Let me provide you with the *same exact* functionality, but in a standard function. Keep in mind this is *exactly* what is happening in the above code, but it may be simpler to comprehend if you're not used to the concision of ES6:

```
function scramble(my_string, my_array) { 
   // create an array to return
   let returnable_array = [];

   // loop through the provided array. 
   // string index is the array key: 0,1,2,3
   // array_index is the value of the array keys: 0,3,2,1

   for(let [string_index, array_index] of my_array.entries()) {

   // we assign the character at string index 
   // to the value index inside the returnable array

    returnable_array[array_index] = my_string[string_index];
   } 

   // we turn the array into a string
   let returnable_string = returnable_array.join("");

   // we return the string
   return returnable_string
}
```

---

### Example:

```js
    function scramble(my_string, my_array) { 
       let returnable_array = [];
       for(let [string_index, array_index] of my_array.entries()) {
        returnable_array[array_index] = my_string[string_index];
       } 
       returnable_string = returnable_array.join("");
       return returnable_string
    }


console.log(scramble("abcd", [0,3,1,2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to put the string into a new array:

```
    function scramble(str, arr) {
        //validate if the array has elements
        if (arr && arr.length) {
            //create a new array
            const strArr = []
            arr.forEach(index => {
                //push each character by index
                //As noted by Barmar you could either use
                //str.charAt(index) or str[index]
                //as both will return the character at the specified index
                strArr.push(str.charAt(index))
            })
            //return a new string
            return strArr.join('');
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also just use `str[i]`, no need to call a function.

Comment: You are right Barmar, as a string also behaves like an array.